# How to Insert and Retrieve plain HTML into MySQL table - Using PDO/PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

**Updated Question:**

I have successfully added some html to my MySQL database using this code:

```
     $emailaddress = $_SESSION["email_address"];
    ..
     $html_content = '<div> Hello</div>';
      ..

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(htmlcontent) VALUES (:hContent)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':hContent' => $html_content));
```

Except that I need it to only insert into the "htmlcontent" column for the email which matches `$emailaddress.` So I tried including `WHERE` in my PDO statement like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(htmlcontent) VALUES (:hContent) WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->execute(array(':hContent' => $html_content, ':email' => $emailaddress));
```

but it returns the following error:  Perhaps I should use Update instead? I'll try now

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE email = 'my@domain.com'' at line 1'
 in /home/fire18/public_html/login/private.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /home/fire18/public_html/login/private.php(31): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/firer18/public_html/login/private.php on line 31
```

**Old question:**

I'm trying to insert plain html code into my MySQL database, in order to retrieve it later from a different page. I'm confused as to how I get the html into the database, and then later retrieve it. I've read that I should use `TEXT` and also `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prepare the html for the `INSERT`. But I'm using PDO and so I don't know what to do.

So, let's say I want to get this html into my database:

```
<li>
      City Scene 
     <input id="keepbox5" type="checkbox" name="keepbox5"  />
       <label for="keepbox5">Keep</label>
        <input id="cbox5" type="checkbox" name="cbox5" class="cboxes"/>
         <label for="cbox5">Show</label>  
         <div class="tinybox">
           <img src="http://www.example.com/img/temp.jpg" alt="tinypic" id="tinypic" style="display:none;">   
         </div>         
</li>
```

I need to `INSERT` it into my `users` table, but I'm sure this is wrong:

```
$htmlCode = mysql_real_escape_string(<li> City Scene <input id="keepbox5" ...[ALL HTML]... </li>);  

$query = " 
            INSERT INTO users (  
                db_html_code 
            ) VALUES ( 
             $htmlCode
            ) 
        ";
```

Since I'm using PDO like so:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
```

Then at the end when I need to retrieve the data, I read that I need to use `stripslashes()` but again, don't know if this applies.

1. How do I properly insert plain html into my DB (PDO using PHP?
2. How do I then request/display the stored html on other pages?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: the same way you insert any string

Comment: So is my example above correct then? `$htmlCode = mysql_real_escape_string(<li> City Scene <input id="keepbox5" ...[ALL HTML]... </li>);  `  I'm guessing not since mysql is apparently deprecated, but I don't know how it should look.

Comment: no its invalid php syntax

Comment: Are you willing to show me how it should look? I still don't understand how to retrieve the data either. If you're not willing, then ok.

Comment: after 59 questions, i would like to think you could read the manual.

Comment: Isn't this site a repository of knowledge that others can find useful too? Which section of which manual are you saying I should read, php, or mysql?  I've read relevant pieces of both but am not sure which terms I should be looking for. Plus I'm confused as to what is considered the ideal approach in my situation, so I was asking for input

Comment: You can't mix MySQL APIs. Connect with PDO and stay with PDO. Don't go using other functions such as `mysql_`, it won't work. Here https://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

Comment: Thanks Fred. Can you show me an example of how to use PDO instead of `mysql_` here? Even a link explaining the syntax is fine, I simply don't know what to search for... "replace mysql_ with PDO when trying to insert html into mysql" ?  I've been going in circles for hours

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Fred, I've updated my question to a more specific problem (I've successfully stored html, just can't get the `WHERE` statement to work). Can you take a quick peek? Thank you

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it. I provided an answer. Thanks again for your link

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by including:

```
 $emailaddress = $_SESSION["email_address"];
    ..
     $html_content = '<div> Hello</div>';
  ...
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET htmlcontent=:hcontent WHERE email=:email");
    $stmt->bindValue(":hcontent", $html_content);
    $stmt->bindValue(":email", $emailaddress);
    $stmt->execute();
```

in my PHP document. Thanks to Fred for the link which guided me in the right direction.